# Find the nth term of geometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given the geometric series $1+2+4+8...$

Find the sum between (inclusively) the 5th term and the 15th term.

I just solved for the 5th term. $r=2$  so just multiply the 4th term $8\cdot2$ to get 16.

The 15th term= 
$15=1*2^n$

$15=2^{7.5}$

$S_{15} = 1[(2^{7.5})-1/2-1]$

$S_{15} = 180$
is that correct?

Comment: I have no idea how you get a $7.5$. Also what is that $r=2$? Your new edit is hard to understand.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** for any geometric sum we have: $$\sum_{i=0}^n a^i =\frac{1-a^{n+1}}{1-a}$$ so take $n=5$, $n=15$ and $a=2$.

Comment: when n = 5 is the answer 63?

Comment: Yes is (1-2^6)/(1-2)=63!!

Comment: Since the sum is inclusive, you need to calculate $S_{15} - S_{4} = S_5 + S_6 + \cdots + S_{14} + S_{15}$.